# I Try to PutPixel (RGB pixel)using PIL ,But always Fail

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I Try to using PIL.Image.putpixel(xy,color) ,But always fail. 
It's work for put singel channel graycolor PIL.Image.putpixel((x,y),255)
But I want to put RGB color to this picture.

trackback -> TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Not: 123.jpg is grayscale picture.

Code Below:

```
from PIL import Image 
img = Image.open("123.jpg")
img.convert('RGB')
for x in range(img.size[0]):
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        img.putpixel((x, y), (255, 255, 255))
img.save("temp.jpg")
img.show()
```

Comment: Try `img = Image.open("123.jpg").convert('RGB')`

Comment: `convert` "[r]eturns a converted copy of this image"; it does not change the original. Per [the documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Image.convert()` method returns an altered copy without changing the original, but you actually want to use the altered version, so replace:

```
from PIL import Image 
img = Image.open("123.jpg")
img.convert('RGB')
```

with

```
from PIL import Image 
img = Image.open("123.jpg").convert('RGB')
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
img.putpixel(...)
```

(Change im to img)

After correcting that, it should work.

Comment: Sorry , I fixed it (Change im to img) But still not working

Comment: That's strange... I copied your code and it worked for me with a jpg image. Perhaps your version of PIL is outdated (in which case update it with pip). I don't think I can really help with this much more, sorry.

Comment: Pillow version: 5.1.0, PIL version: 1.1.7